# horizontal scroll with images with swipe gesture in android

Tags: java, android, scrollview, swipe

I want to have a scroll/swipe multiple images in android
I thought using ViewPager but I think this is not the best way to go for because I would scroll/swipe big number of images that could be over 1000 Images, thus ViewPager is not the right way to go for!

I will also have 4 layers in the same activity

```
<[          ]> layer1 // scroll/swipe left and right
<[          ]> layer2
<[          ]> layer3
<[          ]> layer4
```

I tried to use ImageSwitcher, it works fine but it doens't have scroll effect, the image should moves with the finger of the user. So I think the purpose here is more about scrolling than swiping!

this is what I did so far

layout.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
   android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
   android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
   android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
   app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
   tools:context="com.combyne.app.ScrollActivity"
   tools:showIn="@layout/activity_scroll">

   <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="200dp"
       android:id="@+id/ImageSwitcher"
       android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
       android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
       android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
       android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
       android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
       android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
       android:layout_gravity="center_vertical">

       <ImageView
           android:id="@+id/imageView1"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_gravity="center"
           android:scaleType="centerCrop"
           android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>
   </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

ScrollActivity.java

```
public class ScrollActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
   private ScrollView Switch;
   ImageView images;
   List<RequestCreator> ImagesUrl = new ArrayList<RequestCreator>();

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_scroll);
       Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
       setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

       FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
       if (fab != null) {
           fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
               @Override
               public void onClick(View view) {
                   Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                           .setAction("Action", null).show();
               }
           });
       }

       ImagesUrl.add(Picasso.with(ScrollActivity.this).load("http://img..."));
       ImagesUrl.add(Picasso.with(ScrollActivity.this).load("http://img..."));
       ImagesUrl.add(Picasso.with(ScrollActivity.this).load("http://img..."));

       final ListIterator<RequestCreator> Images = ImagesUrl.listIterator();

       Switch = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.ImageSwitcher);
       images = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
       final Animation animationOut = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.slide_right_to_left);
       final Animation animationIn = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.slide_left_to_right);


       //Switch.setOutAnimation(animationOut);
       //Switch.setInAnimation(animationIn);
       Switch.setOnTouchListener(new OnSwipeTouchListener(ScrollActivity.this) {
           public void onSwipeLeft() {
               Toast.makeText(ScrollActivity.this, "Left " + String.valueOf(Images.hasPrevious()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               if (Images.hasPrevious()) {
                   Switch.startAnimation(animationIn);
                   Images.previous().into(images);
               }
           }
           public void onSwipeRight() {
               Toast.makeText(ScrollActivity.this, "Right " + String.valueOf(Images.hasNext()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               if (Images.hasNext()) {
                   Switch.startAnimation(animationOut);
                   Images.next().into(images);
               }
           }
       });
   }
}
```

Comment: Try to see RecyclerView with Horizontal LinearLayoutManager. It may help you

Comment: @ajantha RecyclerView is the correct way to do it thanks you a lot